# Illustrator: How can I fill stroked shapes with a color? TONS OF THEM

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created a detailed pattern on illustrator and I used the paint brush and used a stroke color with an empty fill, so it became transparent. I didnt think it through, and there actually should have been a fill color in the shapes that I created, I wanted the fill color to be white. Now when I try to add a background, it actully effects all of the shapes. I'll attach and example of what I am working on. But is there a quick way so that I can fill all of the outline shapes with white? THERE ARE TONS and I really dont want to click on all of them individually to change it to white. I can't seem to figure out the best way. I used the paint bucket tool, and the fill selection option. I really hope there is a quicker way...[image: here is the example.]
As you see in the picture, theres a white background, and I am trying to fill the shapes that have the maroon outline to white but it is all transparent.

Comment: `Select > Same > Stroke Color` maybe?

Comment: If Discreetthinker's after all the transparent shapes, it seems like Select > Same > Fill Color might be the key.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really impossible to answer effectively without examining the actual file in question.

Comment: I'm voting to close because it's basic Illy functionality :-\

Comment: Should I attach the PDF file so you can open it on illustrator? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a one-off (meaning you have to do this once) here's how I'd approach it:

1. Select ALL
2. Duplicate
3. Union

You now have a copy of all the 'blobs' as one large complex shape. Now you can:

4. Give this shape a background color of white (no stroke)
5. Send to back.

You now have all of your blobs 'backed' with a white blob of the same shape. Now you can create a background color and send it to back .

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help
1. create a white square or rectangle like covering your vectors from the top
2. send it to back by right clicking on the rectangle Arrange>Send to back
3. select all your vectors, open the pathfinder window and look for something called "Divide"
4. now manually delete the background alone.

**This is not a difficult process if you know what you are doing!**

**I don't have enough reputation to insert images which explains clearly**

Answer (score 0):

1. Isolate the shapes you want to modify. Do this by selecting anything else and moving them to another layer, and then lock that layer (or select **Object>Lock Selected**)
2. Select everything that's not locked (all your shapes). **Ctrl/Cmd-A**
3. In the Appearance panel, set the fill for the selected shapes.